# Taking A Screenshot & Restarting A Browser After A Scenario Failure With CucumberJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm trying to do a relatively simple scenario with cucumberjs. Namely after a scenario failure I would like to restart the browser so that it is back to an initial state for the next scenario. Here is my attempt

```
this.After({timeout: 30 * 1000}, function (scenario)
{

    if(scenario.isFailed())
    {

        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (buffer)
        {

            console.log("Restarting The Browser As We Got A Failure");

            browser.restart();

            console.log("Finished Restarting The Browser");

            return scenario.attach(new Buffer(buffer, 'base64'), 'image/png');

        });

    }

});
```

which is implemented in a cucumberjs hook that runs at the end of a test scenario. However, when the framework comes around to use the browser in the next test scenario it throws an exception like the following

```
[firefox #01]    Step Definition: StepDefinitions\_Lpewf_Tc_04_steps.js:6
[firefox #01]    Message:
[firefox #01]      UnsupportedOperationError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
[firefox #01]          at WebDriverError (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:26:26)
[firefox #01]          at UnsupportedOperationError (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:435:26)
[firefox #01]          at checkHasNotQuit (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:378:15)
[firefox #01]          at WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:323:5)
[firefox #01]          at WebDriver.findElements (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:897:22)
[firefox #01]          at C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:141:44
[firefox #01]          at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
[firefox #01]          at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
[firefox #01]          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
[firefox #01]          at C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
[firefox #01]      Error
[firefox #01]          at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:371:27)
[firefox #01]          at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:83:30)
[firefox #01]          at ElementFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:685:22)
[firefox #01]          at [object Object].EmployerEnterCodeAndLogin (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\PageObject\_External_Login_Page.js:181:38)
[firefox #01]          at ModuleLoginPageExternal.EnterEmployeeCodeAndContinue (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\ModuleHelper\_Module_External_Login.js:27:40)
[firefox #01]          at World.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bxb145\WebstormProjects\_System_Test_Project\StepDefinitions\_Lpewf_Tc_04_steps.js:22:47)
```

I suppose why is this happening and what do I need to do, so I can use the browser again as per normal after a failure/restart of the browser. Many thanks in advance. Btw the screenshots are been generated as per normal when the JSON are been converted to HTML reports.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code but using callbacks, maybe you can try this:

```
    this.After(function (scenario, callback) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (base64png) {
                var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64png, 'base64');
                scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
                callback();
            }, function (err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it is related to the following issue referenced on github

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2001

use of callbacks doesn't solve this :(

I have opened a new issue to account for this in any case

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3595